# How to add date field to Drupal?

Tags: drupal

There is way to add date to the post in Drupal?
For example [here](http://nineteenfifteen.prototype-interactive.com/node/68), under the image there is date (static date, I put this date in the editor), but maybe there is way to configure drupal to add this date automatically?

Comment: $node->created will get you the `timestamp` then you can put that in the http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7 `format_date` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this to your `node-blog.tpl.php` theme file.

```
'<span class="date">'.format_date($node->created, 'custom', "d F Y").'</span>'
```